# Layer for collision of rigid body

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am trying to define a layer for my rigidbody to ignore collision only from this layer. Can the layer to be ignored be named through script?

Current:

```
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(0, 11); //Layer number 11 = "Ignore Collision"
```

Target:

```
Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision("Ignore Collision"); //Layer number 11 = "Ignore Collision"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`LayerMask.NameToLayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.NameToLayer.html)

```
Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(LayerMask.NeToLayer("Default"), LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Collision"));
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)